# Stochastic, two timesframes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need an alarm in PineScript. I have two different timeframes and I want to create an alarm when both stochastics are below 20 and above 80 at the same time and when a crossover from K to D and vice versa takes place.

I have already programmed the stochastic signals, I actually just want to know how to get the signal from both timeframes.